# Unmarshal yaml while keeping extra parameters

Tags: go, yaml, unmarshalling

I've been trying to write a custom `UnmarshalYAML` function that will unmarshal a yaml to a struct and also keep unexpected parameters saving them into a map into the struct itself.

I've tried writing this (https://go.dev/play/p/azf2hksriQ1) but, of course, I get an infinite loop when I try to unmarshal the struct inside the `UnmarshalYAML`.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to make this work?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I've done this by unmarshing everything into a `yaml.Node`, and pulling out only the things I want. This is useful especially if you want to preserve comments and other formatting — but maybe heavy for your use-case depending on how many "known" fields you have. You could unmarshal into a `map[string]any` and deal with type switching.

Comment: There's also the [`github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure`](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) package which allows you to 1) unmapshal (anything) to a, say, `map[string]interface{}` and then 2) unmarshal _that_ into a proper custom `struct` user-defined type while being able to save all fields which get "unused" during that process into a separate place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple wrapping technique where you define a type alias for your original type (so `yaml.Unmarshaler` won't call your `UmarshalYAML` method) and create a struct which embeds all known and unknown parameters.

```golang
type Foo struct {
    Param1     string         `yaml:"param1"`
    Param2     []int          `yaml:"param2"`
    // NOTE: we explicitly ignore this parameter so it won't be 
    // eventually unmarshaled 
    Extensions map[string]any `yaml:"-"` 
}

// UnmarshalYAML implements the yaml.UnmarshalYAML interface.
func (f *Foo) UnmarshalYAML(value *yaml.Node) error {
    // Here we are wrapping Foo, so it will be unmarshaled
    // using without calling foo.UnmarshalYAML
    type Wrapped Foo
    // NOTE: for yaml it's required to provide inline
    // option if we would like to embed
    var val struct {
        Wrapped    `yaml:",inline"`
        Extensions map[string]any `yaml:",inline"`
    }
    if err := value.Decode(&val); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *f = Foo(val.Wrapped)
    f.Extensions = val.Extensions
    return nil
}
```

[Playground Link](https://go.dev/play/p/4c05D-PKSvz)

Comment: Great idea! I think I'll use this one.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your type with an unmarshaler type, which then calls `Decode` on the wrapped value:

```golang
type Foo struct {
    Param1     string         `yaml:"param1"`
    Param2     []int          `yaml:"param2"`
    Extensions map[string]any `yaml:"extensions"`
}

type FooUnmarshaler struct {
    Foo
}

// UnmarshalYAML implements the yaml.UnmarshalYAML interface.
func (f *FooUnmarshaler) UnmarshalYAML(value *yaml.Node) error {
    // ... snip ...

    // call Decode on the contained value, which will use default decoding
    if err = value.Decode(&f.Foo); err == nil {
        return nil
    }

    // ... snip ...
}

func main() {
    // ... snip ...

    // user your unmarshaler type
    foo := FooUnmarshaler{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(y), &foo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("Error unmarshaling: %v", err))
    }

    // access the actual data via foo.Foo
    spew.Dump(foo.Foo)
}
```

[Playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/Vp8oyAh2KzR), output:

```
(main.Foo) {
 Param1: (string) (len=4) "test",
 Param2: ([]int) (len=3 cap=3) {
  (int) 2,
  (int) 4,
  (int) 6
 },
 Extensions: (map[string]interface {}) (len=1) {
  (string) (len=5) "x-foo": (string) (len=3) "bar"
 }
}
```

Comment: thank you for replying! making a wrapper is a good idea but I think I prefer it best to be inside the UnmarshalYAML itself like @2r2w suggested